# capture optional URL parameter as a local variable

Tags: c#, api

I am trying to create a dual purpose API endpoint.  The idea is, if the user passes in the optional parameter `checkExistence` then the response will be true or false, depending upon whether or not the formulaId + bucket + scenarioName combination exists in the underlying database table.  On the other hand, if the `checkExistence` parameter is not passed in then the response will either be 404 not found or the data (if the combination does not exist) or the data (if the combination does exist).  Here is the code so far:

```
[HttpGet("{scenarioName}/{bucket}/{formulaId}/{checkExistence?}")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string scenarioName, DateTime bucket, string formulaId)
{
    var dto = await DataService.GetAsync(new object[] { formulaId, bucket, scenarioName });

    string? checkExistence = "";

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkExistence))
    {
        if (dto == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(dto);
    }
    else
    {
        return (dto == null) ? Ok(false) : Ok(true);
    }
}
```

When the endpoint is hit it's acting as though `checkExistence` is always empty, even if a value is passed in the URL for that param.  I suspect this is because  `{checkExistence?}` from the URL is not being assigned to the local variable `checkExistence`...but I don't know how to go about making that assignment to test out that theory.  Is there a way to make this assignment?  And are there any other reasons the API could be acting this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional route parameter needs to be included as an optional parameter in the method signature. You can then remove the variable declared within the method:

```
[HttpGet("{scenarioName}/{bucket}/{formulaId}/{checkExistence?}")]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(string scenarioName, DateTime bucket, string formulaId, string checkExistence = null)
{
    var dto = await DataService.GetAsync(new object[] { formulaId, bucket, scenarioName });

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkExistence))
    ...
}
```

See [Optional URI parameters and default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#optional-uri-parameters-and-default-values) for more details.